# Discord js. Bot is not replying to messages

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

```
client.on("message", message =>{
  if(message.channeltype = 'dm')
    if (message.content === "confess")
      message.channel.send("OOOOOOoooooo A SECRET??!?!?! WHAT IS IT?!??!") 
      message.channel.awaitMessages("response", message =>{
      C = message.content
      message.reply("Um.... theres two servers that this bot works on. 1: Loves in the snow or 2:Moomins and Shep's Therapy Service. Pick a number to send it to one of them")
      client.on("message", message => { //////// SWITCH THIS LINE OUT FOR THE THING THAT WAITS FOR NEW MESSAGES
      if (message.content === "2")
        WDI = message.author
        WDID = message.author.id
        message.channel.get(WDIC2).send("Ok ok so who did it is" + WDI + "and their id is" + WDID)
        message.channel.get(CC2).send(C)
    
      if (message.content === "1")
        WDI = message.author
        WDID = message.author.id
        message.channel.get(WDIC1).send("Ok ok so who did it is" + WDI + "and their id is" + WDID)
        message.channel.get(CC1).send(C)
        
    })
        
      })})
```

Why does my bot not reply to my message?
I first put in confess then it would say the message but it doesnt detect that I continue and reply to that. WHat do I do?

Answer (score 1):

Okay first off, try to be a lot more specific when asking questions there is a stackoverflow guide on how you should ask them effectively. Right now you are being unclear and I'm going to have to assume some stuff. Also, include a stack trace whenever possible, which there should have been as you provide some invalid properties, if you don't have one please include that there is not a stack trace in the question.

There is a lot of things wrong with this code. First off, the reason your bot isn't responding to you at all is because `message.channeltype` is not a property. Use `message.channel.type` instead. There is also something wrong with your message.channel.awaitMessages(). You are passing in a "response" string as a parameter, where there should be a filter. Since you don't need a filter since it is a dm channel you can just pass it in as null `message.channel.awaitMessages(null, msg => { });`. And awaitMessages is not the right call here. Await messages takes in messages in a certain time period, then resolving a promise with all of the collected messages. You should be using a [discord.js collector](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html). You should also not be using client.on("message") here. I'm assuming that you want to wait for messages in any channel after somebody "shared their secret". You can do that with a collector. If you want to collect messages all over the bot, or in just one discord server channel (using the filter which can be found on the docs) you can use a collector. This will wait for, in a number of milliseconds, for any event and filter out event triggers that aren't allowed. And when it gets it, it will run a lambda. Like this:

```js
const filter = m => m.channel === message.channel && m.author = message.author); // The filter that will sort out the messages
const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, { time: 30000 }); // creates a collector that will wait for 30 seconds

collector.on('collect', m => { // When somebody sends a message
    // ...
    if (message.content === '2') {
        // ...
    } else if (message.content === '1') {
        // ...
    } else {
        message.reply('you need to say either 1 or 2. Please try again.');
        return;
    }
    collector.stop(); // Makes sure that the collector no longer will receive anymore messages.

});
```

Final code (fill in the gaps I'm not going to code it all for you)

```js
client.on("message", message => {
    if(message.channel.type = 'dm')
        if (message.content === "confess")
        const filter = m => m.channel === message.channel && m.author = message.author; // The filter that will sort out the messages
        const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, {time: 30000})
        collector.on('collect', message => {
            const otherCollector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, { time: 30000})
            otherCollector.on('collect', message => {
                if (message.content === '2') {
                    // ...
                } else if (message.content === '1') {
                    // ...
                } else {
                    message.reply('you need to say either 1 or 2. Please try again.');
                    return;
                }
                collector.stop(); // Makes sure that the collector no longer will receive anymore messages.
            })
        })
})
```

Also, before asking on any forum or discord server, always look up the documentation. It helps out 99% of cases, unless the docs is absolutely garbage.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the docs. I'd say that the [Discord.JS](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) docs are a pretty handy reference.

For the first part, `message.channeltype` is not a real property, and do not use `=`. That is for setting variables, use `==` or `===` instead ([What is the difference?](https://www.guru99.com/difference-equality-strict-operator-javascript.html)). You can use `message.channel.type` or you can use `instanceof` as followed: `message.channel instanceof Discord.DMChannel`. Replace Discord with whatever your Discord.JS import variable is called.

Your `if`s are missing some `{}`, they should be used as followed.:

```js
if(message.channel instanceof Discord.DMChannel) {
   //If the channel IS a DMChannel
} else return;
```

FYI, if you're planning to make multiple commands, I'd use a switch, and a way to convert `message.content` to arguments (string array).

`message.channel.get` is not a thing, use `client.channels.cache.get`. The variables `C`, and `WDI` / `WDID` need to have `var` before them.

Then you need to add a filter plus maximum messages, time limit, and minimum messages for your `awaitMessages` function. Plus you need `then` and `catch`, so now your code might look like this

```js
if(message.channel instanceof Discord.DMChannel) {
    if (message.content === "confess") {
        message.channel.send("OOOOOOoooooo A SECRET??!?!?! WHAT IS IT?!??!")
        message.reply("Um.... theres two servers that this bot works on. 1: Loves in the snow or 2:Moomins and Shep's Therapy Service. Pick a number to send it to one of them") 
        const filter = m => m.author == message.author;
        message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {/* whatever your parameters/limits are */})
        .then(col => {
            if (col.content === "2") {
                /** Add in code */
            } else if (col.content === "1") {
                /** Add in code */
            }
        })
        .catch(col => {/** Whatever you want to do if times up. */})
    }
}
```

You may want to tweak the filter on this.